# How can I solve this type of error in docker?

Tags: dockerfile

I want check my container is working or not. `docker run -p 5500:80 php-web` but it give error. basically code want to on chrome.

```bash
docker run -p 0:8080 php-web
```

```
(env) vipul@vipul-Lenovo-Ideapad-330-15AST:~/python-Venvironments/Python_Real_Time_Coding/ec2$ docker run -p 0:8080 php-web
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Feb 13 16:02:02.191565 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/7.4.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 13 16:02:02.191906 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
 ^C[Tue Feb 13 16:03:25.784221 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```